# is there way to view a Swing app remotely?

Tags: java, swing, browser

I want to show my app conveniently without the hassle of carrying a laptop or distributing an obfuscated Java app.

Is there an easy way to view my Swing app in a browser.  I do not necessarily need the command buttons to work (but it would be nice if they did), I just want to see the pixels from anywhere on the internet.  I have graphs built from JChart2D.

**Edit:** The screen updates after a configurable period and 15 seconds is typical but if the desktop updates every 15 seconds and the browser image at a much slower rate, say, 1 minute, that would be okay.

**Edit:** What I have is primarily a desktop app in that it being a desktop app satisfies 98% of the requirements but if I can see it or use it remotely without a re-write that would give me the extra 2% (see it 1%, use it 1%).

Comment: Can you use remote desktop or VNC?  If not, maybe screenshots in a browser window if you don't mind too much if the app is not functional?

Comment: I need updates about once every 15 seconds, not just static screen shots. A remote desktop sounds like a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

For that purpose, the recent [Webswing](http://www.webswing.org/) may be perfect. It seems fully functional. There are some glitches and I miss the cursors. Alas, the remote applications are displayed on the server, too, whether you want it or not.

Comment: Hi. Are you still using webswing (now=jan 2016)? Any advice, or tips?

Comment: No, I've never used it as I don't need it.

Answer (score 2):

There is not many solutions for it but this easisest way is [JNLP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Web_Start).

JNLP is an XML-based technology for launching Java executables over the Web. Just imagine that you could specify the classpath resources in your application (images, JAR files, properties, files, etc.), scattered over the Web and giving their URLs, instead of relying on the local file system as normal Java applications do. This feature would give you the capability of deploying your application automatically (that is, installing needed application files and launching them properly) just by declaring where your files are on the Web. And it is far easier than Applets which can create a lot of troubles to you because of strict permissions at browser.

An example of JNLP is [here](http://pedroassuncao.com/2010/10/java-web-start-jnlp-simple-example/) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-web-start-jnlp-tutorial-unofficial-guide/).

Comment: I tried a stock broker's JNLP client recently.  My guess it has to download the byte code so it looks like there is a non-trivial IP property theft risk.  Still, it looks like a practical solution if the downloads are limited to only people I have given passwords to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think I would recommend this (because it has security implications and firewall issues) but it is possible to run a Java / Swing application using a remote X11 server.

Here are some relevant links:

- [Remote X Apps mini-HOWTO](http://zweije.home.xs4all.nl/xauth.html#toc9)
- [X Over SSH2 - A Tutorial](http://www.vanemery.com/Linux/XoverSSH/X-over-SSH2.html)

but there is probably more uptodate information in your Linux documentation.

Another idea is to make a demonstration movie.

Answer (score 1):

One other possibility (not necessarily a good one, but easy to implement) might be to use the [`java.awt.Robot`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class.

Using this class, you could periodically take a snapshot of the screen, using `#createScreenCapture(...)`, and write this out to disk using [`javax.imageio.ImageIO`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html).

It would then be straightforward to create an HTML page that displayed this image, and auto-refreshed periodically.  A little bit complicated and circuitous, but may let you re-use existing infrastructure.

Answer (score 0):

VNCj ([official page](http://emblemparade.net/projects/vncj/), [SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vncjlgpl/)) is an older project which provides an implementation of AWT on a VNC server.  Swing runs on top of that.  Unlike WebSwing, no UI appears on the server when running VNCj.