# How to access a server running Java Application

Tags: java, server, client

I need to develop an Application for a country Survey. I chose Java for my Proramm Language. I want to run the Java-Swing Application on a Server and access it with e.g. an IPad. Is this possible and how?

Thanks in advance! :)

P.S: I tried it already with JNLP Service but it won't work.

Comment: do you mean with "I chose Java" as in for the back-end(server) or for the front-end generation (or a separate client) as well?

Comment: `Java-Swing Application` using an `Ipad`. I believe it ***was*** possible using an applet before (not even talking about the mobile age...), but I am pretty sur no browser allow a java application embedded in an HTML page. You will need to change the client to either create an app or a website that will communicate to a JEE backend.

Comment: @JorisDR. just for the backend

Answer (score 2):

[Swing](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_(Java)) was not designed for remote access. It is intended for desktop (fat client) applications on desktops or workstations, not servers. So no, you can not access your swing application from an iPad just like that. There are some projects that might work (related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7625529/is-there-way-to-view-a-swing-app-remotely)) but they are not natively web applications. JNLP for example would still be executed on the client, not the server.

I would rather look into web technologies like [JSF](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaServerFaces/article.html) or [Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) or [Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-start).

Comment: or if the way swing works is the way he wants to program, [vaadin](https://vaadin.com/) give the ability to make cross browser web apps, but programmed fully in java (and a css file)